# Podio Ruby Rails shows "nomethoderror"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having problems with the Podio_rails_sample. I've included my leadsController and leads.rb files. The line that gets hung up is `field['config']['settings']['allowed_values']`.

Line 25 is the problematic one:

```
NoMethodError in LeadsController#new
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #25):

23 app = Podio::Application.find(APP_ID)
24 field = app.fields.find { |field| field['external_id'] == 'status' }
25 field['config']['settings']['allowed_values']
26  end
27
28  def self.create_from_params(params)

Rails.root: c:/Sites/podio_rails_sample


app = Podio::Application.find(APP_ID)
field = app.fields.find { |field| field['external_id'] == 'status' }
field['config']['settings']['allowed_values']
  end

  def self.create_from_params(params)

Rails.root: c:/Sites/podio_rails_sample



-----------------------------------
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_collections, :only => [:new, :edit]


  def index
    @leads = Lead.all
  end

  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
  end

  def create
    Lead.create_from_params(params['lead'])
    redirect_to leads_path, :notice => 'Lead created'
  end

  def edit
    @lead = Lead.find_basic(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    Lead.update_from_params(params[:id], params['lead'])
    redirect_to leads_path, :notice => 'Lead updated'
  end



  def destroy
    Lead.delete(params[:id])
    redirect_to leads_path, :notice => 'Lead deleted'
  end


  #protected

    def load_collections
      @lead_contacts = Lead.space_contacts
      @sales_contacts = Lead.users
      @statuses = Lead.statuses
    end

end

-------------------------------------

 - leads.rb file

class Lead < Podio::Item
  APP_ID =12328033  
  SPACE_ID =3204114

  # Find all items in the Leads app
  def self.all
    collection = self.find_all(APP_ID)
    collection[:all]
  end

  # Find valid lead contacts in the space
  def self.space_contacts
    Podio::Contact.find_all_for_space(SPACE_ID, :order => 'contact', :limit => 12, :contact_type => 'space,connection', :exclude_self => false) rescue []
  end

  # Find valid sales contacts in the space
  def self.users
    Podio::Contact.find_all_for_space(SPACE_ID, :order => 'contact', :limit => 12, :contact_type => 'user', :exclude_self => false) rescue []
  end

  # Find valid statuses
  def self.statuses
app = Podio::Application.find(APP_ID)
field = app.fields.find { |field| field['external_id'] == 'status' }
field['config']['settings']['allowed_values']
  end

  def self.create_from_params(params)
    # raise fields.inspect
    self.create(APP_ID, { :fields => fields_from_params(params) })
  end

  def self.update_from_params(id, params)
    self.update(id, { :fields => fields_from_params(params) })
  end

  #
  # Map the field values return by the Podio API to simple getters
  #

  def organization
    field_values_by_external_id('company-or-organisation', :simple => true)
  end

  def lead_contact
    field_values_by_external_id('contacts', :simple => true).try(:[], 'name')
  end

  def sales_contact
    field_values_by_external_id('sales-contact', :simple => true).try(:[], 'name')
  end

  def potential_revenue_value
    field_values_by_external_id('potential-revenue').try(:first).try(:[], 'value').to_i
  end

  def potential_revenue_currency
    field_values_by_external_id('potential-revenue').try(:first).try(:[], 'currency')
  end

  def probability
    field_values_by_external_id('probability-of-sale', :simple => true)
  end

  def status
    field_values_by_external_id('status', :simple => true)
  end

  def followup_at
    field_values_by_external_id('next-follow-up').try(:first).try(:[], 'start').try(:to_datetime)
  end

  protected

    def field_values_by_external_id(external_id, options = {})
      if self.fields.present?
        field = self.fields.find { |field| field['external_id'] == external_id }
        if field
          values = field['values']
          if options[:simple]
            values.first['value']
          else
            values
          end
        else
          nil
        end
      else
        nil
      end
    end

    def self.fields_from_params(params)
      {
        'company-or-organisation' => params[:organization],
        'contacts' => (params[:lead_contact].present? ? params[:lead_contact].to_i : nil),
        'sales-contact' => (params[:sales_contact].present? ? params[:sales_contact].to_i : nil),
        'potential-revenue' => { :value => params['potential_revenue_value'], :currency => params['potential_revenue_currency'] },
        'probability-of-sale' => params[:probability].to_i,
        'status' => params[:status],
        'next-follow-up' => DateTime.new(params['followup_at(1i)'].to_i, params['followup_at(2i)'].to_i, params['followup_at(3i)'].to_i).to_s(:db)
      }.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }
    end

end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: https://github.com/podio/podio_rails_sample